# Printing BlockUIContainer to XpsDocument/FixedDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument, xpsdocument

**Question**

1. How do you print a FlowDocument that have `BlockUIContainer`?
2. How can I force a Measure/Update/Arrange on a FlowDocument?

**Background**

I have a generated `FlowDocument` with paragraphs of text with a few `Rectangle` elements filled `DrawingBrushes` from a resource dictionary and `BlockUIContainer` with custom controls.

The document renders correctly when viewed in any of the FlowDocument* controls **HOWEVER** when the document is converted to a FixedDocument/XpsDocument, none of the `Rectangle` or `BlockUIContainer` elements render.

I'm almost certain it is because the control has **not been measured/arranged**, however cannot figure out how to force that to happen before it is converted to the XpsDocument.

- I have walked the `LogicalTree` recursively and done the following,

  ```
  UIElement element = (UIElement)d;
  element.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
  element.Arrange(new Rect(element.DesiredSize));
  element.UpdateLayout();
  ```

  where `d` is a `DependencyObject`. I can see that this sets the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties when break-pointed in the debugger.
- I have tried forcing the `Dispatcher` to render as suggested by [Will ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728059/73025).

**Code used to print the XpsDocument**

```
public class XpsDocumentConverter
{

    public static XpsDocumentReference CreateXpsDocument(FlowDocument document)
    {
        // Need to clone the document so that the paginator can work
        FlowDocument clonedDocument = DocumentHelper.Clone<FlowDocument>(document);

        Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("pack://temp_{0}.xps/", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        Package pkg = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        PackageStore.AddPackage(uri, pkg);
        XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(pkg, CompressionOption.Normal, uri.AbsoluteUri);

        XpsSerializationManager rsm = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDocument), false);
        DocumentPaginator paginator = new FixedDocumentPaginator(clonedDocument, A4PageDefinition.Default);
        rsm.SaveAsXaml(paginator);

        return new XpsDocumentReference(ms, xpsDocument);
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm also using a custom `DocumentPaginator` named 'FixedDocumentPaginator'; however I will not post that code as I doubt the issue is there as by the time it starts paginating the document in `GetPage(int pageNumber)` everything has already been converted a `Visual` and it is too late for layout.

---

**Edit**

Hmm. As I typed this, a thought just occurred to me that the **cloned document** may not have had a `Measure/Arrange/UpdateLayout` done.

**Question:** How can I force a Measure/Update/Arrange on a FlowDocument?

A possible hack that I could work would be to show the cloned document in one of the FlowDocumentViewers (perhaps off-screen).

Another possible solution that I just learnt about and haven't tried would be to call: `ContextLayoutManager.From(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher).UpdateLayout();`

`ContextLayoutManager` walks the logical tree for you and updates the layout.

**Code used for cloning the document**

```
public static FlowDocument Clone(FlowDocument originalDocument)
{
    FlowDocument clonedDocument = new FlowDocument();
    TextRange sourceDocument = new TextRange(originalDocument.ContentStart, originalDocument.ContentEnd);
    TextRange clonedDocumentRange = new TextRange(clonedDocument.ContentStart, clonedDocument.ContentEnd);
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            sourceDocument.Save(ms, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
            clonedDocumentRange.Load(ms, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        }

        clonedDocument.ColumnWidth = originalDocument.ColumnWidth;
        clonedDocument.PageWidth = originalDocument.PageWidth;
        clonedDocument.PageHeight = originalDocument.PageHeight;
        clonedDocument.PagePadding = originalDocument.PagePadding;
        clonedDocument.LineStackingStrategy = clonedDocument.LineStackingStrategy;

        return clonedDocument;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {               
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting this as future reference for others that are having similar rendering issues with FlowDocument/FixedDocument/XpsDocument.

A few things to note:

- `BlockUIContainers` are not cloned when you use the above method. This was not immediately obvious until I printed the logical tree out the debug window using some helper methods (these methods are posted below - they are incredibly useful).
- You need to display the document in a viewer and briefly show it on screen. Below is the helper method that I wrote to do this for me.

**ForceRenderFlowDocument**

```
private static string ForceRenderFlowDocumentXaml = 
@"<Window xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation""
          xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
       <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name=""viewer""/>
  </Window>";

public static void ForceRenderFlowDocument(FlowDocument document)
{
    using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(ForceRenderFlowDocumentXaml)))
    {
        Window window = XamlReader.Load(reader) as Window;
        FlowDocumentScrollViewer viewer = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(window, "viewer") as FlowDocumentScrollViewer;
        viewer.Document = document;
        // Show the window way off-screen
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        window.Top = Int32.MaxValue;
        window.Left = Int32.MaxValue;
        window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        window.Show();
        // Ensure that dispatcher has done the layout and render passes
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => {}));
        viewer.Document = null;
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I just added `window.ShowInTaskbar = false` to the method as if you were quick you could see the window appear in the taskbar.

The user will never "see" the window as it is positioned way off-screen at `Int32.MaxValue` - a trick that was common back in the day with early multimedia authoring (e.g. Macromedia/Adobe Director).

For people searching and finding this question, I can tell you that **there is no other way** to force the document to render.

**Visual and Logical Tree Helpers**

```
public static string WriteVisualTree(DependencyObject parent)
{
    if (parent == null)
        return "No Visual Tree Available. DependencyObject is null.";

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (var indentedTextWriter = new IndentedTextWriter(stringWriter, "  "))
    {               
        WriteVisualTreeRecursive(indentedTextWriter, parent, 0);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}

private static void WriteVisualTreeRecursive(IndentedTextWriter writer, DependencyObject parent, int indentLevel)
{
    if (parent == null)
        return;

    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    string typeName = parent.GetType().Name;
    string objName = parent.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) as string;

    writer.Indent = indentLevel;
    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0:000}] {1} ({2}) {3}", indentLevel, 
                                                              String.IsNullOrEmpty(objName) ? typeName : objName, 
                                                              typeName, childCount)
                    );

    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childCount; ++childIndex)
        WriteVisualTreeRecursive(writer, VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex), indentLevel + 1);
}

public static string WriteLogicalTree(DependencyObject parent)
{
    if (parent == null)
        return "No Logical Tree Available. DependencyObject is null.";

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (var indentedTextWriter = new IndentedTextWriter(stringWriter, "  "))
    {
        WriteLogicalTreeRecursive(indentedTextWriter, parent, 0);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}

private static void WriteLogicalTreeRecursive(IndentedTextWriter writer, DependencyObject parent, int indentLevel)
{
    if (parent == null)
        return;

    var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent).OfType<DependencyObject>();
    int childCount = children.Count();

    string typeName = parent.GetType().Name;
    string objName = parent.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) as string;

    double actualWidth = (parent.GetValue(FrameworkElement.ActualWidthProperty) as double?).GetValueOrDefault();
    double actualHeight = (parent.GetValue(FrameworkElement.ActualHeightProperty) as double?).GetValueOrDefault();

    writer.Indent = indentLevel;
    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0:000}] {1} ({2}) {3}", indentLevel,
                                                              String.IsNullOrEmpty(objName) ? typeName : objName,
                                                              typeName, 
                                                              childCount)
                    );

    foreach (object child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent))
    {
        if (child is DependencyObject)
            WriteLogicalTreeRecursive(writer, (DependencyObject)child, indentLevel + 1);
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
#if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine("--- Start -------");
    Debug.WriteLine(VisualAndLogicalTreeHelper.WriteLogicalTree(document));
    Debug.WriteLine("--- End -------");
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, just been through this hell myself, you helped a lot =)

Comment: What's going on in `XpsDocumentReference`? I keep trying to print from a `PrintDialog` by pulling the `DocumentPaginator` from the XPS document via `GetFixedDocumentSequence().DocumentPaginator`. I get a Xaml parse exception resulting from an InvalidURI exception. Apparently the fixed document URI is mangled somehow.

Comment: @AustinMullins take a look at my answer over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647401/documentviewer-to-richtextbox-binding-error

It shows the implementation of the `XpsDocumentReference`. It has been a few years since I looked at XPS. Happy to revisit and help. It would be a good opportunity to create a open source library.

Comment: @AustinMullins Reading that answer again I now remember the pain I went through to figure out that Invalid URI exception.

Comment: Hi @Dennis, so how did you manage to clone FlowDocument with BlockUIContainer's?

Comment: @RuslanVeselov honestly cannot remember, it is almost 6 years ago. i'll see if i can find the source code and look for you.

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8a7b9af-2487-4041-af4d-68752d249b2b/losing-tablecell-alignment-and-image-when-printing-flowdocument), and it helped me get the printing of the FlowDocment without having to render it off screen...So I hope it can help you!!

```
String copyString = XamlWriter.Save(flowDocViewer.Document);
FlowDocument copy = XamlReader.Parse(copyString) as FlowDocument;
```

Comment: I ran into an infinite recursion loop when embedding an `ItemsControl` into a `BlockUIElement` during `XamlWriter.Save`. I think the problem is that some property of the ItemsControl references its container, and the `MarkupWriter.RecordNamespaces` function recursively navigates each property of the item to save.